# Permanent redirect of similar links

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I'm working for a client that has old site still running, but will make the switch to our server later today.

Now, since they used some custom CMS, and we used wordpress, the links are different. So when we make the switch, google will most likely throw bunch of errors about old links pointing to nowhere.

So I need to redirect them. The problem is that the old links look something like this:

*articles*:

```
www.examplesite.com/artiklar/CAT_NAME/20160125/article_name
```

*categories*:

```
www.examplesite.com/tagg/CAT_NAME
```

And on our new site we have

*articles*:

```
www.examplesite.com/CAT_NAME/article_name
```

*categories*:

```
www.examplesite.com/CAT_NAME
```

Now the categories should be easier to redirect, I'm guessing something like this should work in my `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteRule ^tagg/(.+)$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

But what about the article links? Also is the category redirect ok?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this `.htaccess` file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^tagg/([^/]+)$ /$1 [L,R=301]
    RewriteRule ^artiklar/([^/]+)/[0-9]+/([^/]+)$ /$1/$2 [L,R=301]
    RewriteRule ^special/grand-news /special/ [R=301,L]
    RewriteRule ^special/([^/]+)$ /special/$1.php [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: I've read just now about htaccess and this looks ok to me. We'll see if it will work. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Hi @FlorianLemaitre, sorry to bother, but can you help me with another redirect? I have `www.examplesite.com/special/grand-news` that should go to `www.examplesite.com/special/` and `www.examplesite.com/special/subpage` should go to `www.examplesite.com/special/subpage.php`. I tried with `RewriteRule ^/special/grand-news / [R=301,L]` and `RewriteRule ^/special/([^/]+)$ ^/special/$1.php [R=301,L]` But nothing happens (well I don't get sent to the right page). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Thanks! I was close with that second one XD